# jQuery Mobile, setting 'Go' button on iPhone keyboard with multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile with asp.net and I've got a few buttons on my search form. I want it so when a user clicks the 'Go' button which comes up on the iphone keyboard by default it selects my search option. At present it loads the last loaded button or the top one.

Here is my html:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblWhat" CssClass="style=color:Red;" runat="server" Visible="false">Please Enter What you want to search for</asp:Label>
            <label for="what">What:</label>
              <asp:Label ID="lblWhere" CssClass="style=color:Red;" runat="server" Visible="false">Please Enter where you would like to search, or click Use My Location</asp:Label>
            <input type="text" name="what" id="tbWhat" value="" runat="server" placeholder="What" />


                <br />

            <label for="where">Where:</label>
            <input type="text" name="where" id="tbWhere" value="" runat="server" placeholder="Where"/>

               <br />

             <input type="text" name="long" id="tbLong" runat="server" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" />
              <input type="text" name="long" id="tbLat" runat="server"  style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" /> 

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
            if (navigator.geolocation) {  
                document.write('<input type="button" onclick="getLocation()" value="Use My Location" />');
            } else {  

            }  
        </script>

    <input type="button" onclick="clearForm()" value="Clear" /> 
 <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAccess" runat="server" Text="Access Requirements" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server"  Text="Search" />


       </div>
```

It's btnSearch that I would like to run when Go is pressed (or enter in a browser)

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this best answers your question; http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/04/421647.aspx
use  to set your default button; e.g.